# How would i be able to present this information in a rich text box or any type of visual outputs. C#

Tags: c#, .net

This is the code and i need to present the output on screen in a windows form. Would prefer if it is a text box.

```
var res = (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
           group x by (string)x["Weather"] into y
           select new { Key = y.Key, Count = y.Count() }).ToArray();
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? and what is the data you're using? What is the Model?

Comment: I am using a DataTable. I want to count and output the number of times each element occurs in a specific column. "Weather" in the code is an example column.

Comment: If it's a database table like visual you're after, you could put it into a dataset and represent it on the form similar to: [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15fb34e8-a260-4981-b671-806f8276e285/showing-data-table-in-windows-forms)

Comment: How do you want your result to be printed on the Text Box?

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset Indicates this should be possible:

```
var res = from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
       group x by (string)x["Weather"] into y
       select new { Key = y.Key, Count = y.Count() };

var newdt = res.CopyToDataTable();

datagridview1.DataSouce = newdt;
```

All that remains is for you to drop a DataGridView control on your form,
Ensure it's AutoGenerateColumns property is set to true, and give it a better name than datagridview1 (on the form and in the code above)

Comment: Question title says "or any type of visual outputs"

Comment: I was unable to implement the following line: var newdt = res.CopyToDataTable(); i get an error about anonymous types and generic T values.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data to List

```
var r = (from x in test.AsEnumerable()
                 group x by (string) x["Weather"] into y
                 select new
                     {
                     Key = y.Key, Count = y.Count()
                     }).ToList();
```

Then Iterate and get all the data to string and assign that to textbox.Text Property.

```
 string result = "";
        foreach ( var weatherData in r )
            {
            result += weatherData.Key + " " + weatherData.Count + "\r\n";
            }
myTextBox.Text = result;
```

Comment: It shows as "(Collection)" in the list box how would i be able to display each element separately

Comment: What control do you want your data? and how do you desire the output?

Comment: The second solution worked, however, is there anyway i can add this to a DataGridView

Comment: If it worked, mark it as accepted. How do you want the view for DataGridView? like Key and Count?